# Sumcheck protocol - how are these 2 polynomials different?

Tags: polynomials, interactive-proof-systems

I am going through Justin Thaler's book - https://people.cs.georgetown.edu/jthaler/ProofsArgsAndZK.pdf - "Proofs, Arguments, and Zero-Knowledge"

He is describing the Sumcheck Protocol on Page 34

$H = \sum_{b_1 \in \lbrace 0,1 \rbrace} \space \sum_{b_2 \in \lbrace 0,1 \rbrace} \space ... \space \sum_{b_v \in \lbrace 0,1 \rbrace} g(b_1, b_2,...,b_v)$

> At the start of the sum-check protocol, the prover sends a value
> $C1$ claimed to equal the true answer (i.e., the quantity H defined in Equation (4.1)). The sum-check protocol proceeds in $v$ rounds, one for each variable of $g$. At the start of the first round, the prover sends a polynomial $g1(X1)$ claimed to equal the polynomial $s1(X1)$ defined as follows:
>
> $s1(X1) = \sum_{(x_2,...,x_v)\in {\lbrace 0,1\rbrace}^{v−1}} g(X1, x_2,...,x_v) \in {\lbrace 0,1\rbrace}^{v−1}$ - $Eq (4.2)$

Further ahead on Page 35, he writes

> The remaining issue is the following: can $V$ efficiently compute both $g1(r1)$ and $s1(r1)$, in order to check that the Equation $g(r1) = s(r1)$ holds? Since $P$ sends $V$ an explicit description of the polynomial $g1$, it is possible for $V$ to evaluate $g1(r1)$ in $O(deg1(g))$ time. In contrast, evaluating $s1(r1)$ is not an easy task for $V$, as $s1$ is
> defined as a sum over $2^{v−1}$ evaluations of $g$.

---

I understand how the Prover creates polynomial $g1$ from $g$ (Eq 4.2). What I don't understand is the difference between $g1$ & $s1$. Prover sends Verifier only $g1$ - where does Verifier get $s1$ to evaluate it at $r1$?

Comment: @D.W.  I had mentioned the page number 35 of the 2nd quote already. Now added page 34 for the 1st quote

Answer (score 1):

Your question is answered in the book itself, in the sentence you quote and the next few sentences thereafter.  The Verifier doesn't get $s_1$.  As the book says:

> evaluating $s_1(r_1)$ is not an easy task for $\mathcal{V}$ [...]
>
> rather than evaluating $s_1(r_1)$ on her own, $\mathcal{V}$ instead *recursively* applies the sum-check protocol to evaluate $s_1(r_1)$.

Moreover if you look at the specification of the protocol on p.34, you will see that the Verifier never computes or receives $s_1$.

Comment: Yes, that's my question - The book says "Hence, rather than evaluating s1(r1) on her own". My question how can the Verifier evaluate s1 when they don't know s1? What's written seems to imply that Verifier can evaluate s1 but it would be time consuming.

Comment: I think I kind of get it now - the Verifier can create s1 the same way the prover did from g. I keep forgetting that this isn't ZK - i.e. the Verifier knows the original polynomial g. Is this correct?

Comment: @user93353, I already answered the question you asked in the question/post ("where does Verifier get $s_1$?").  The answer: The Verifier doesn't get $s_1$.

Comment: So the verifier creates s1 from g exactly the same way prover creates s1 from g, right?